# Can you ignore LLBLGen header comments in TFS?

Tags: tfs, llblgenpro

I use LLBLGen Pro version 4.2 to generate my data layer and TFS to manage my source code. When LLBLGen generates my data layer it prefixes every file with a comment block like this:

```
' ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' // This is generated code. 
' //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' // Code is generated using LLBLGen Pro version: 4.2
' // Code is generated on: Tuesday, 14 July 2015 7:42:47 a.m.
' // Code is generated using templates: SD.TemplateBindings.SharedTemplates
' // Templates vendor: Solutions Design.
' // Templates version: 
' //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Even if the entity hasn't *really* changed since the last version TFS notices that the file is different and when I review my pending changes I end up with a whole lot of files that are functionally identical, but which now have an edit history.

This makes it difficult to find the *actual* code changes.

Is there a way to configure LLBLGen and/or TFS so that this doesn't happen?

Note: In LLBLGen I can configure it to not emit the date time when it generates the source code using the setting:

Project ->
Settings ->
Conventions ->
LLBLGen Pro runtime framework ->
"tdl emit time date in output files"

This means the comment block is identical and there are no actual code changes.

But TFS still notices that the file has 'changed' when it hasn't.

Comment: That's a TFS-thing, it shouldn't show up as a changed file in your commit though, can you check the history?

Comment: I question why you store generated code in version control. It is more common to ignore it and the build script regenerate when needed.